# Statement Vs. Block

Tags: java, if-statement, block

I am a new java user. Recently I have learned that in java each statement is terminated with a semicolon (;) and each block is delimited by a pair ob curly braces - `{}` (please correct me if I am wrong).

But in many places I have found writers are saying that `if` statement. So my question is what is the difference between **`statement`** and **`block`** in java?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *But in many places I have found writers are saying that `if` statement.* What do you want to say?

Comment: yes, they are two different things, and hence have two different names. Read on in your Java Tutorials.

Comment: Formal definitions: [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html)

Comment: *"in java each statement is terminated with a semicolon"* No.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html) defines blocks and statements formally. To simplify what it says:

- It is *not* true that every statement in Java ends in a semicolon. This is a convenient way to think about them, but it's not formally correct.
- Some statements include a semicolon in their definition. Those are usually simple statements. For example:

  - The *empty statement* is just a semicolon: `;`.
  - An expression statement is one of a permitted set of expressions, followed by a semicolon. `new ClassName();`, `System.out.println();`, `i++;` etc.
- A block is a type of statement that contains declarations and other statements surrounded by braces `{ int i = 1; System.out.println(i); }`.
- Some statements are built using other statements. Their definition does not include a semicolon. If the sub-statement ends in a semicolon, then those statements end in a semicolon. The `if` statement falls into this category. It is built as `if ( expression ) statement` . So if the *`statement`* part inside it has a semicolon, it ends in a semicolon. If the *`statement`* inside it happens to be a block (which is a type of statement!), then it ends in a brace:

  ```
  if ( a == b )
     System.out.println(a);
  ```

  vs.

  ```
  if ( a == b ) {
     System.out.println(a);
  }
  ```

  In the first format, the substatement of the `if` is an expression statement (a method invocation is an expression statement, and expression statements end in a semicolon).

  In the second format, the substatement of the `if` is a block statement, which contains a single expression statement. So the `if` ends in the block`s brace, not in a semicolon.

Bottom line: statements are defined by belonging to certain formal categories. Some of them end in a semicolon, some do not.

Answer (score 1):

**Your definitions are correct.** `if` is a statement even if it does not end with semicolon.

Generally speaking if the program construct produces a value then it is expression, otherwise it is statement. In Java unlike other languages (Scala, Groovy, ...) `if` is statement and not expression.

Answer (score 1):

If is actually both typically.

The if statement itself is just that, a control flow statement. If the statement is evaluated to true it executes the statement, or block after it. In other words, the block after an if is not required if you just wanted to execute a single line of code.

So, and pardon my of the cuff java, you could have either of these:

```
if(someboolean)
    DoSuff();
```

Or

```
 if(someboolean) {
    DoSuff();
  }
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html

Comment: *"If is actually both typically"* both what? Statement and block?

Comment: Yup. The conditional logic is a statement, typically followed by a block. However if you felt like it you could just follow it up with a single statement to execute. The risk is that you forget and try to add another line, which without the block syntax will not be conditional.

Comment: I can't see how `if`s can be considered blocks: a block is a sequence of statements we want to execute in the given order, and that's clearly far from what we expect from an `if`, which is a *statement*.
(also, "statement evaluated to true" is misleading, statements are something we want to evaluate for their side-effects, they don't evaluate to values)

Comment: I'm sorry if I am being confusing. "if" is a statement. The "if" itself is *not* a block. However, it is typically immediately followed by a block. The "if" contains an expression that is evaluated. In the case that the expression is equal to true, the block or statement that immediately follows the "if" is executed. It is of the form: [ControlStatement] (expression) [Statement]||{Block}

Answer (score 0):

A statement is part of a block. A block contains statements separated by semicolons, but is also a statement itself. In BNF:

```
statement := block | ...
block := '{' { block | (statement ';') } '}'
```

Comment: That's not how blocks are made in Java, block statements are not separated by semicolons, that's exactly what confuses the OP.